# how to print list in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i print these function in one column.

```
  item = stock.stock_list(location_name)



for x in sorted(item):
    """Stock list of given location"""
    print (x)

for y in sorted(item): 
    """Stock price of give location and stock list"""
    print ("{0:.2f}".format(stock.stock_price(y)))  

for z in sorted(item):  
    """stock qty of given location name and item"""
    print(stock.stock_quantity(location_name, z))
```

output is

```
Elephant foot yam
Kai-lan    
16.25
13.96  
90
18
```

want it to be

```
Elephant foot yam         16.25             90
Kai-lan                   13.96             18
```

the first one has to be left aligned and 20 wide, the second being right aligned and 8 wide and the third being right aligned and 6 wide.

---

also another question.

how do i print location_id from below in brackets?

```
print(toptext, location_name, location_id)
```

output is

```
Stock summary for location 123456789
```

i want it to be

```
Stock summary for  Wellington (123456789)
```

i tired

```
 print(toptext, location_name, "(", location_id ,")" )
```

but there is a space between the brackets like so ( 123456789 )

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the second part of your question, is it also your goal to not have "location" but "Wellington" there? So is it a bug that location is not replaced by the actual location? If so, you need to give insight how location_name is set.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question try this:

```
print "(%s)" % location_id
```

If you want to print more variables you can do it like this:

```
print "%s %s (%s)" % (toptext, location_name, location_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first part of the question, you need to print one entire row in each loop

```
for x in sorted(item):
    """Stock list of given location"""
    print (x)
    print (spacing)
    """Stock price of give location and stock list"""
    print ("{0:.2f}".format(stock.stock_price(y)))
    print (spacing)
    """stock qty of given location name and item"""
    print(stock.stock_quantity(location_name, z))
```

For laying it out better, Python lets you do " " * n
so you can calculate the number of spaces required between each cell in the row and do something like:

```
" " * (spacing_length - len(cell))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can archieve all that with the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function.

Your first question would be:

```
"{:<20}{:>8.2f}{:>6}".format(item, price, stock)
```

In your second question it should be

```
"{} {} ({})".format(toptext, location_name, location_id)
```

For further information read the format documentation.